# Cannot invoke "registerClass" on UITableView in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift

New to Swift, this worked fine for me with Objective-C. Not sure if this is a syntax issue or if I have my project set up incorrectly.

First of all, this is the error that I'm seeing (on line 5 of JobsViewController, the line that starts with self.tableView.registerClass):

`Cannot invoke 'registerClass' with an argument list of type '(UITableViewCell.Type, forCellReuseIdentifier: String)'`

**JobsViewController**

```
class JobsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    }
}
```

Google hasn't been very helpful, would appreciate some help!

Comment: Your example code is incomplete as there is no property `tableView` in `JobsViewController`.

Comment: Probably JobsViewController should inherit from UITableViewController instead of UIViewController.

Answer (score 4):

Works fine in **Swift 3**

```
tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 var cell : UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell()

 feedTableView.registerClass(cell.classForCoder, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellidentifier")
```

Try with above lines of code

Answer (score 1):

### Swift 5

Please use like,

```
self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not set up the custom class - class name in the storyboard for this table.
You need to select JobsViewController from the pull down list.
Then you will get

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
```

in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.tableView.delegate = self 
            self.tableView.dataSource = self
            self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")
      return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 4+, in the ViewDidLoad of the ViewController containing the list put something like

```
self.listView.register(UITableView.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CellItentifier")
```